# Tengo problemas para crear un php que juegue el juego del mastermind

Tags: php, xampp, while, sintaxis

Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio en el cual dice lo siguiente: Utilizando una sentencia while, hay que construir un juego de mastermnd. El juego permitira un numero ilimitado de intentos y comunicara al usuario el numero de intentos que ha necesitado. El codigo que he utilizado tiene un problema de sintaxis en la linea 11 que no soy capaz de solucionar. He aquí el codigo. Muchas gracias y perdonen las molestias

```
    <?php
$int = 0;
$res = mt_rand(0,10);
$cor = 0;
while ($cor<1)
{
  $pre = mt_rand(0,10);
  if ($pre<$res)
  $int++;
  echo "El numero" .$res. "es demasiado grande. Este es su intento" .$int;
  elseif ($pre>$res)
  $int++;
  echo "El numero" .$res. "es demasiado pequeño Este es su intento" .$int;
  else
  echo "¡ENHORABUENA! Has necesitado" .$int. "intentos";
  $cor++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas de sintaxis vienen por la estructura del código: no metes las llaves {} de bloques tras los **if** y esto provoca que  **else** aparezca como una sentencia independiente del if
Con la descripción no puedo saber si esta solución funciona exactamente como quieres, pero elimina el problema, corrije la posición de las llaves si es necesario.

```
    $int = 0;
    $res = mt_rand(0,10);
    $cor = 0;
    while ($cor<1)
    {
      $pre = mt_rand(0,10);
      if ($pre<$res){
         $int++;
         echo "El número " .$res. " es demasiado grande. Este es su intento " .$int;
      }
      elseif ($pre>$res){
         $int++;
        echo "El número " .$res. " es demasiado pequeño Este es su intento " .$int;
    }
      else{
          echo "¡ENHORABUENA! Has necesitado " .$int. " intentos ";
          $cor++;  
          }
    
    }
```

Siempre es recomendable usar las llaves {} aunque solo encierren una línea de código.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aun asi ahora tengo el problema de que esto para en el primer intento, en vez de parar cuando fuera la respuesta correcta.